# First time Permission Error when Creating overlay widget for my Android App

Tags: java, android, overlay

I have a floating widget which is displayed as an overlay (think FB messenger chat bubble).
If I don't have required permission, my code request user for permission to display over other apps but in between switching from app to settings screen, it shows "App keeps stopping" in UI and when I grant permission, instead of going back to app. The app closes. But after giving the permission when I start app and click on Show widget it shows properly. The problem seems to be for first time when requesting permissions. What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

1. Code for FloatingViewService.java : https://pastebin.com/Yn24kJ4r
2. Code for PermissionRequestActivity.java : https://pastebin.com/KWwLb1Hx
3. Code for MainActivity.java : https://pastebin.com/Fp3QL6kN

Error : https://imgur.com/a/q2J5ZAx

Below is the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.datebud, PID: 14310
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.datebud.FloatingViewService@355a10d with Intent { cmp=com.example.datebud/.FloatingViewService }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Params must be WindowManager.LayoutParams
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4839)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Params must be WindowManager.LayoutParams
                                                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.applyTokens(WindowManagerImpl.java:162)
                                                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
                                                                                                        at com.example.datebud.FloatingViewService.onStartCommand(FloatingViewService.java:32)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4821)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```